methodSignature.getParameterNames() is null in Spring Boot 3.2 when Running Junit Tests together but tests pass individually
Please I'm facing an issue when running JUnit tests after migrating to spring boot 3.2. When Running Tests together they fail but pass individually. methodSignature.getParameterNames() is null


Im using Intellij IDEA. The maven project dependency tree is:
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-to-slf4j:jar:2.21.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:2.0.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- jakarta.annotation:jakarta.annotation-api:jar:2.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:2.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.9.22.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat:jackson-dataformat-csv:jar:2.15.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:7.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.16.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-collections4:jar:4.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math3:jar:3.6.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.16.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.zaxxer:SparseBitSet:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.21.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.poi:poi-ooxml-lite:jar:5.3.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.xmlbeans:xmlbeans:jar:5.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.26.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.github.virtuald:curvesapi:jar:1.08:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.13.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:10.1.30:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:10.1.30:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.micrometer:micrometer-observation:jar:1.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.micrometer:micrometer-commons:jar:1.12.10:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-http:jar:1.1.22:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-codec-dns:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-native-macos:jar:osx-x86_64:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver-dns-classes-macos:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-classes-epoll:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- io.projectreactor.netty:reactor-netty-core:jar:1.1.22:compile
[INFO] |  |        \- io.netty:netty-handler-proxy:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |           \- io.netty:netty-codec-socks:jar:4.1.113.Final:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |     \- io.projectreactor:reactor-core:jar:3.6.10:compile
[INFO] |        \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.4:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:3.1.7:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:2.0.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:5.19.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-validation:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:10.1.30:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.hibernate.validator:hibernate-validator:jar:8.0.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- jakarta.validation:jakarta.validation-api:jar:3.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.5.3.Final:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor:jar:3.2.10:compile (optional) 
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-freemarker:jar:3.2.10:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.33:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-context-support:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] +- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.18.34:compile
[INFO] +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.13.1:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-access:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:2.0.16:compile
[INFO] +- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.4.14:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.4:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:3.2.10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:3.2.10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:3.2.10:test
[INFO] |  +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.9.0:test
[INFO] |  +- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:jar:4.0.2:test
[INFO] |  |  \- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:jar:2.1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:2.5.1:test
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:9.6:test
[INFO] |  +- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:3.24.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.awaitility:awaitility:jar:4.2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.5.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-jcl:jar:6.1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:6.1.13:test
[INFO] |  \- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:jar:2.9.1:test
[INFO] +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:jar:5.10.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:jar:5.10.3:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:jar:1.3.0:test
[INFO] |  |  +- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:jar:1.10.3:test
[INFO] |  |  \- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:jar:1.1.2:test
[INFO] |  +- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:jar:5.10.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:jar:5.10.3:test
[INFO] |     \- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:jar:1.10.3:test
[INFO] +- com.flextrade.jfixture:jfixture:jar:2.7.2:test
[INFO] +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:5.7.0:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.14.19:test
[INFO] |  +- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:jar:1.14.19:test
[INFO] |  \- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:3.3:test
[INFO] +- org.jsoup:jsoup:jar:1.14.3:test
[INFO] +- com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:jar:4.12.0:test
[INFO] |  \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:jar:1.9.25:test
[INFO] |     +- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:jar:1.9.25:test
[INFO] |     |  \- org.jetbrains:annotations:jar:13.0:test
[INFO] |     \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:jar:1.9.25:test
[INFO] +- com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:jar:4.12.0:test
[INFO] |  \- junit:junit:jar:4.13.2:test
[INFO] |     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:2.2:test
[INFO] \- com.squareup.okio:okio:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]    \- com.squareup.okio:okio-jvm:jar:3.4.0:test
[INFO]       \- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:jar:1.9.25:test

The maven-complier-plugin is configured like this
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <parameters>true</parameters>
    </configuration>
</plugin>

I tried this configuration for the plugin:
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <compilerArgs>
                <arg>-parameters</arg>
                <arg>-verbose</arg>
            </compilerArgs>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!
I have tried this solution but it's not working for me: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/38721

Are you using maven or gradle ? Please share your build file and see how you use the dependency of AspectJ, and how the plugin is configured.

@драган-јованковић. I attached the maven project dependeny tree and maven-complier-plugin configuration

Welcome to SO. I fixed your image links, so the pictures are displayed inline now. I also added syntax highlighting for your XML snippets.

Please learn how to ask a question on SO and provide a minimal, complete, and verifiable example, ideally a minimal Maven project on GitHub. Thank you.

@kriegaex, thank you for making things looking better. Yeah my first question in SO so plz bear with me. Ok Ill try to create a simple example because the project is a corporate one and I can't share it as it is.

@kriegaex, I figured after a long Divide and conquer approach that the issue was caused by an old unit test in the project doing Mockito.clearAllCaches() in its setup() method. Please do you know an explanation?

Was anything unclear about "minimal, complete, and verifiable example"? Your comment here is evidence that my request made sense to begin with and now makes more sense than ever.

@kriegaex, as I said this is a corporate project that has thousands of files, so to have "minimal, complete, and verifiable example" is not something easy to do. So never mind if you dont have something of the top of your head and plz take it easy and no need for your last comment.

It is almost trivial to create an MCVE from any big project by simply removing more and more modules, classes, methods. You shave off as much a possible, until a minimal version reproducing the error remains. This is a pretty mechanical process, not requiring any advanced skills. Just create a new branch, commit after each successful removal. Revert after each unsuccessful one. In the end, rename modules, classes, methods to anonymise the reproducer.
